# checkstyle JavadocType only on interfaces

Tags: java, interface, checkstyle

As we are drowning in thousands of checkstyle rules, I want to relax them (if only to stop devs from ignoring them).  One of the rules I want to relax is the [JavaDocType](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html#JavadocType) check: Only on interfaces should javadoc be mandatory, not on other public classes.  Unfortunately, I don't see an 'interface' [Scope](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/property_types.html#scope). Has anyone a suggestion to make this possible without writing our own check?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like the right thing:

> **tokens**
>   definitions to check subset of tokens [INTERFACE_DEF](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/TokenTypes.html#INTERFACE_DEF), [CLASS_DEF](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/TokenTypes.html#CLASS_DEF)

Try this:

```
<module name="JavadocType">
   <property name="tokens" value="INTERFACE_DEF"/>
</module>
```

Comment: I must be blind to have missed that. Thanks.

Comment: @user844382, it is a nice habit on SO to *upvote* useful answers by clicking on the up arrow on their left :-)